# Haskell , calculate the product of a list of integers like this:

Tags: haskell

My task is:

> For a list of numbers, calculate the product of the difference between
>   two consecutive elements if the elements are positive or the maximum
>   of the elements, otherwise.

I can use only list comprehension.

Example: `prod [7,5,4, -3,2] == 2 * 1 * 4 * 2 == 16`

```
prod :: [Int] -> Int
prod xs = product [ x | x <- xs, x > 0 ]
```

I don't know how to take the next character to make the difference if they are positive numbers. Can someone please guide me a little?

Comment: With difference do you mean the *absolute value* of the difference? Do `(2,4)` and `(4,2)` both map on `2`?

Comment: @Madalina please validate the answer of Willem if it does solve your problem. It is important for others to know whether an answer has been accepted or not

Answer (score 3):

There are two problems that arise here:

- obtaining every two consecutive numbers; and
- calculating the difference or the maximum.

My guess is that it is better to resolve this problems separately. The second can best be resolved by using a separate function: `diff_or_max` for instance:

```
diff_or_max :: (Num a, Ord a) => a -> a -> a
diff_or_max x y | x >= 0 && y >= 0 = abs (x-y)
                | otherwise = max x y
```

The first problem could be solved by using the `tails` function of the `Data.List` module:

```
import Data.List(tails)

special_prod :: (Num a, Ord a) => [a] -> a
special_prod xs = product [ diff_or_max x x2 | (x:x2:_) <- tails xs ]
```

This yields:

```
*Main Data.List> special_prod [7,5,4, -3,2] 
16
```

Comment: Thank you, so in this case i need a help function. Thank you  again

Comment: @Madalina: you do not *need* a help function in the sense that it is a hard requirement, it only makes it easier if you solve separate problems with separate functions, structures, etc.

Comment: Can I ask you something that it's quite similar? I'm not sure if I understood very well :)

Comment: @Madalina: feel free to ask

Comment: Instead of `[ diff_or_max x x2 | (x:x2:_) <- tails xs ]`, you can also use `zipWith diff_or_max xs (tail xs)`.

Comment: @Jedai: yeah indeed. I had the idea to minimize the "difference" between the question and the answer (for instance by not introducing much more functions). But evidently there can be more elegant ways.